# Android - How can i select a strings.xml without Localization

Tags: java, android, xml, string, switch-statement

Is it  possible to manually select a `strings.xml` file without changing the language of your device?

I would like to have  `Button` to switch between two languages, but all i found is to use the build-in feature of android studio to create different `strings.xml`, which are selected by your localization.

Comment: Did you found any global solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a different `strings.xml` you have to switch localization. This can be done programmatically but is highly not recommended because you will mess with the system.

You can create a different resource XML file that you can put your strings there, give them a unique id and fetch them in the same way (R.id.your_string)

EDIT:

You create an XML file that you put into /res/values. This file will declare some strings in the same way the strings.xml does. With ids, values and everything. Then from the code what you do is to conditionally change strings. For example :

if (this){
//get the string from strings.xml here (R.strings.your_string
else {
//get the string from your_file.xml here the same way you did above.
{

For more info check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am not sure how to use the new resources file. Do i have to read a string from that file in every TextView or is it possible to globally change the "@string/[..]" to a "@newresource/[...]"

Comment: Edited my answer please check to see if there is something you do not understand.

Comment: Okay, i got it, thank you very much! But there is no way to globally change all strings without explicit changing every TextView, right? 
Because the strings have to have different names it is not possible to match them i guess. And there is no way to give them the same name.
Well, how it's now i could better place everything in the strings.xml without using another resource

Comment: Well there can be. A simple way I can think of is: Declare a boolean value to work as a flag. And put every `textView.setText()` within a condition that goes `if myFlag==true` do this, else do that.

If my answer helped you please accept it, thanks.

Comment: i know what you mean and i implemented it like that. works fine, but i hope there is a solution like: 
two resource files with same string names: <string name="samename">one</string> in resources.xml
and in the resources2.xml <string name="samename">two</string>.
In my java code i want to say: use this resources.xml and if(...) use the strings from resources2.xml