# How to change locale on android

Tags: android, locale, translation

I am trying to change the android Locale

Some of the solutions such as [Android-Localization](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-Localization) are working but only at the beginning. After couple of hours in the background **some** of the items are changing to default

**At first (good):**

[image: good EditText and toolbar]

**After couple of hours in the background (not good):**

Note: Not all is changing! Some still using the correct strings, system still in RTL etc. But, toolbar, drawer, bottom Edit text not good (**even if initiated in the `onCreate`** as suggested in the documentation)

[image: Not good EditText and toolbar]

As my last attempt using [Android-Localization](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-Localization)

```
//Gradle
implementation 'com.akexorcist:localization:1.2.4' 

//App
public class App extends LocalizationApplication {

//..

@NotNull
    @Override
    public Locale getDefaultLanguage() {
        return new Locale( "iw");
    }

}

//Every activity
public class MainActivity extends LocalizationActivity {
//..
}
```

I also checked answers such as

[change app language programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android)

[android how can i select a strings xml without localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098089/android-how-can-i-select-a-strings-xml-without-localization)

BTW - I could see notes saying it is not recommended to change the locale and instead let android system select it, but this is none-sense. A lot of apps are doing it including Whatsapp, Facebook, netflix... Why oh why google always making everything so complicated??

Comment: `onResume()` also you have to setLocale

Comment: When extending the `LocalizationActivity` it already handles that. I also tried to use other manual solutions and  re-activated in the `onResume` but also did not help.

Comment: Please use android locale only check this https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

Comment: I could not get it to work. Did you use it? Did you tested it on android 9? is there any proven source code without any issues? Android will make me crazy, there is nothing simple with what they do.

Comment: please check this one https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-the-app-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: this one also https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I checked many tutorials and i believe i at least understand the problem. The fact that the locale is taken directly from context and there are 3 types of context, not to mention the strings such as activity names taken directly from such as Manifest poses great complexity. I can overcome locale parameters taken from manifest (by re-insert in `onCreate`) and from activity context (by `recreate()`) but it seems i cannot if taken or refreshed from `Application`. Am i wrong? if not, question: for what is the `Application` locale parameter important for, if at all?